# How to check connection with a jsp site via IdHTTP

Tags: delphi, indy, indy10

I have a program in Borland Delphi 7 that uses Indy components and I want to check that my login and password are correct.

This is my current code:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, IdBaseComponent, IdComponent, IdTCPConnection,
  IdTCPClient, IdHTTP, IdIOHandler, IdIOHandlerSocket, IdIOHandlerStack,
  IdSSL, IdSSLOpenSSL, IdCookieManager, StrUtils;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    IdHTTP1: TIdHTTP;
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Edit2: TEdit;
    Label1: TLabel;
    Button1: TButton;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
    IdCookieManager1: TIdCookieManager;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
 post: TStringList;
 poczatek, koniec: integer;
 aStream: TMemoryStream;
 HTML, authToken: string;
 fLogin, fHaslo: string;
begin
 IdHTTP1.HandleRedirects := True;

 fLogin := Edit1.Text;
 fHaslo := Edit2.Text;

 HTML := IdHTTP1.Get('https://e-skok.pl/eskok/login.jsp');
 poczatek := Pos('name="atlassian-token" value="', HTML) +
 Length('name="atl_token" value="');
 koniec := PosEx('"', HTML, poczatek);
 authToken := copy(HTML, poczatek, koniec - poczatek);

 post := TStringList.Create;
 try
   post.Add('atlassian-token=' + authToken);
   post.Add('os_username=' + fLogin);
   post.Add('os_password=' + fHaslo);
 try
   IdHTTP1.Request.ContentType:= 'application/json';
   HTML:= IdHTTP1.Post('https://e-skok.pl/eskok/login.jsp', post);
   Memo1.Text:= HTML;
   Label1.Caption := 'YES';
 except
     if IdHTTP1.ResponseCode = 401 then
       begin
       ShowMessage('Nieprawidłowy login lub hasło.');
       Label1.Caption := 'NO';
       end
      else
      Label1.Caption := ':)';
 end;
 finally
   post.Free;
 end;
end;
end.
```

The problem is when I try to log in, the program always says "Yes" (which mean it's connected, even though login and/or password are wrong).

What is the proper way to check connection with a jsp site via IdHTTP?

Comment: What is the value of HTML and IdHTTP1.ResponseCode?

Comment: Value of HTML is url adress which I want to connect.
Value of IdHTTP1.ResposneCode isn't assigned - programm should check that the ResponseCode is 401 - if it is, then programm should show message "Wrong login or password"

Answer (score 3):

You cannot rely on the `ResponseCode` alone to verify your login, especially when an HTML-based login form is involved.  Yes, `Post()` raises an exception when an HTTP error code is returned.  So the fact that `Post()` is not raising an exception means the server is not reporting an HTTP error.  But the content it is sending back could be an HTML error page, or even the login page displaying a failure message (which is not uncommon).  So when `Post()` "succeeds", you need to analyze the response to make sure it is what you are expecting.

When I go to `https://e-skok.pl/eskok/login.jsp` in a web browser and input bad credentials, I get redirected back to `https://e-skok.pl/eskok/login.jsp?err=1`.  When `Post()` exits without an exception, you can check the `TIdHTTP.Response` to see if that was the last URL redirected to.

BTW, the `TStrings` version of `Post()` you are calling only supports `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` posts, so setting the `Request.ContentType` to `application/json` is wrong since you are not posting JSON formatted data.  Fortunately, `Post()` replaces the `ContentType` with the correct value.  If you really want to post JSON data, you have to use the `TStream` version of `Post()` instead.

**Update**: after looking at the actual HTML from `https://e-skok.pl/eskok/login.jsp`, I can see that the code you originally showed is incorrect.  You are not parsing the login HTML correctly (there is no `atlassian-token` field present), and you are posting the credentials to the wrong URL using the wrong field names.  You have to post to `https://e-skok.pl/eskok/j2_security_check` instead, and it is expecting the following input fields:

```
j_username
j_password
j_captcha_response
```

That last field in particular requires extra work because it is a dynamically generated captcha.  You would have to parse the HTML to extract the URL of the captcha image (`https://e-skok.pl/eskok/captcha.jsp?d=1410970679796`, where `d` changes every time the page is requested), download the image (you can use `TIdHTTP.Get()` for that) and display it in your app's UI so you can enter the correct text value to post in the `j_captcha_response` field.

Try that, and then report back with your results.

Comment: So, I should change TStringList for TStream?

Comment: No, I was merely pointing out a bug in your code.  No HTML-based login form will ever use JSON to carry the form field values.  Using a `TStringList` is fine as long as the server is excepting `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` formatted data (which is the default unless the HTML `<form>` tag specifies another format, usually `multipart/form-data`).

Comment: So, is it possible to connect with jsp site via Indy components? Or should I change it into another technology/component?

Comment: I also tried to check a specify code from site after log in, but it still don't work correctly.

Comment: @adam.cziker: Of course it is possible, and I told you how. You are just not handling it correctly yet. For instance, when I run the code you showed, the `authToken` is not getting the correct value because `Pos('name="atlassian-token" value="', HTML)` is returning 0. So you are not parsing the login HTML correctly before calling `Post()`, so the login fails.

Comment: @adam.cziker: see the update in my answer. The original code you showed is posting the wrong data to the wrong URL, you need to fix that.

Comment: @adam.cziker: Sorry, but I am not going to sit here analyzing multiple websites for you. You need to learn how to read HTML, and how the HTML `<form>` element in particular operates. It tells you which URL to post to and which parameter values it is expecting. Open a website in your webbrowser and look at its HTML source, locate the `<form>` element you want to post, and write your code to match its parameters accordingly.

Comment: Ok, but should i search in site that i would to log in, right?

Sorry for my silly questions :|